# Typescript omit type by values from array

Tags: typescript

I have this case where i want to remove some keys from an object. What i do i pass the object `user` and and array of available keys that can be deleted. What want is to return the updated user without the keys that are defined in `fields`. I also want typescript to make an error if i try to access an key that is deleted

```
export const removeFieldsUser = (user: User, fields: (keyof User)[]) => {
  fields.forEach((e) => delete user[e])
  return user as Omit<User, keyof typeof fields>
}
```

What i do here is i remove some keys from the object `User`
I want to return the updated User without the deleted keys.

I tried with `keyof typeof fields` but its still there. My intellisense still gives me a hint.

Here is an example:

```
let updatedUser = removeFieldsUser(user, ["name", "age"])
```

Now, `updatedUser` should not contain `name` and `age`

EDIT:

I have made the Function more generic so i can use it with every object

```
export const removeFields = <T, K extends (keyof T)[]>(
  object: T,
  fields: K
) => {
  fields.forEach((e) => delete object[e])
  return object as Omit<T, K[number]>
}
```

EDIT:

I also tried following: Whenever i write an key inside the `fields` parameter, i does not want intellisense to display me the same key twice when i enter CTRL + SPACE to see the suggestions.

I tried following:

```
export const removeFields = <T, K extends (keyof Omit<T, K[number]>)[]>(
  object: T,
  fields: K
) => {
  fields.forEach((e) => delete object[e])

  return object as Omit<T, K[number]>
}
```

This works not fully. It does not show me the same key twice, but it now says `"Type 'is_adult' is not assignable to type ..."`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use generic parameters for the `user` and the `fields`:

```
const removeFieldsUser = <T extends User, K extends (keyof T)[]>(
  user: T,
  fields: K,
) => {
  fields.forEach((e) => delete user[e]);

  return user as Omit<User, K[number]>;
};
```

The key point is `K[number]` which is [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html), basically, every `keyof` of any array includes `number`, which are indexes of the array, thus we get the union of elements of the array

Usage:

```
type User = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  isAdult: boolean;
};


// Omit<User, "name" | "isAdult">
const user1 = removeFieldsUser(
  {
    id: 'asd',
    name: 'dasd',

    isAdult: false,
  },
  ['isAdult', 'name'],
);
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gKClAlgEwC4o5hFcA7AcwG5soKBDAWwmNPOrp1zgEF8AVwA2wYgCMA9pOERGFOgF86mAMaSKpKIgjNJANwgAxXBGH448JKigAeACpQIAD2AQKF2AkQAaKAGknV3dPAAoAawgQSQAzLyQASgBtAF0APlD6QW9iex96GNNzOGJ-fITUNIwCoosAOhjJRABRRlUAC1DQiAqUKvwzCDcobKQkiBSElRwdYEFEChHvKEY4KAB5ZlxgWytfAKSKQWZxJHSlFXVNYCWkAEYbHT1DEzMLPcycLBweIigAclW+H++R+DBYbAB+CBIMw9B4-CEomIMUYwgQoKgikxSX+vAEImAIIBTFY-xS5ToQA)

Comment: Where can I find the documentation about the special syntax K[number]? What does it mean?

Comment: One extra point, if i press CTRL + SPACE, i can see the available keys. Is it possible to show only the keys that arent being used? What i mean is when i pass `["isAdult"]` inside the array and when i now press CTRL + SPACE intellisense still shows me `isAdult` as suggestion

Comment: @bill.gates Unfortunately, that won't be possible, to prevent the compiler to autosuggest already used keys. We can make sure that the content of the array is unique, which will raise an error, but still will suggest used keys. And I think it is going to be really redundant

Comment: @Silvermind you can find it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html)

Comment: @wonderflame Thanks. It's a nice feature, but it looks confusing to me what it means. I understand it, but the logic escapes me. It looks like an abuse of the `number` keyword.

Comment: @Silvermind every array has `number` as its key. If you try `Extract<keyof string[], number>` you will get a `number`

Comment: (continued) it is the same as with `Record<string, number>`, you can access all values just by using `[string]` as a key

Comment: @wonderflame Thanks. TIL. Would have been nice if they explicitly mentioned that or added a link to a page explaining that.